# CSS background-image not showing my image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with `background-image` property in one of my sections. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Elipsis</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body> 
<header id="intro">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
<section id="about">  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>   
<section id="services">  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>   

</main> 
<footer id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
#intro {
    background-image: url(.../.../img/intro.png);
    background-image: url(intro.png);    
    background-image: url(".../.../img/intro.png");
    background-image: url("intro.png"); 
}
```

Index.html is in root folder, css file is in root/css/... and `intro.png` is in both root/img/... and root folders. Why it's not showing? I've read a couple of topics here on stack and some articles from google but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try double dot (../) and if you are using relative, make sure the path is relative to the css file

Comment: Have you tried `url("../img/intro.png");`?

Comment: Does the element with the image have any content or a defined height?

Comment: First thing you should do is check for errors. Open your web inspector and check the console output (i.e. 404 or access denied). If there are no errors check if your `intro` has a height/is visible.

Comment: Yes, I've also added 'url("../img/intro.png");' and again no luck, #intro does not have content or defined height, in web inspector #intro is 1px height. Also, firefox web inspector is saying that it couldn'y load stylesheets, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote that CSS rule only the very last line will apply, which is

```
background-image: url("intro.png");
```

(it overwrites the other lines before it)

So you probably want to change that to

```
#intro {
  background-image: url("../img/intro.png"); 
  height: 300px; /*whatever value, if there is no content */
}
```

Plus, as someone wrote in the comments: if that element has no content and no defined height, it will have height 0, therefore the background image will not be visible.

Comment: #intro {
    background-image: url(".../intro.png"); 
    height: 1000px;
}

and
#intro {
    background-image: url("intro.png"); 
    height: 1000px;
}
Also doesn't work, even with intro.png in root catalog.

Comment: Finally, 'background-image: url("../intro.png"); ' worked, thank you very much. But I don't understand why in so many sites and topics there are 3 dots.

Comment: your solution links to the image in the root folder. What I posted links to the image in the `img` folder

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
background-image: url('../img/intro.png');

I usually drag and drop that image to get the proper path. I hope this helps.

Comment: and also add these properties.background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;